# Elliptical orbit modeling

Tags: mathematics, physics, orbit

I'm playing with orbits in a simple 2-d game where a ship flies around in space and is attracted to massive things. The ship's velocity is stored in a vector and acceleration is applied to it every frame as appropriate given Newton's law of universal gravitation. The point masses don't move (there's only 1 right now) so I would expect an elliptical orbit.

Instead, I see this:

[image: This is what I see]

I've tried with nearly circular orbits, and I've tried making the masses vastly different (a factor of a million) but I always get this rotated orbit.

Here's some (D) code, for context:

```
void accelerate(Vector delta)
{
    velocity = velocity + delta; // Velocity is a member of the ship class.
}

// This function is called every frame with the fixed mass. It's a
// method of the ship's.
void fall(Well well)
{
    // f=(m1 * m2)/(r**2)
    // a=f/m
    // Ship mass is 1, so a = f.
    float mass = 1;
    Vector delta = well.position - loc;
    float rSquared = delta.magSquared;
    float force = well.mass/rSquared;
    accelerate(delta * force * mass);
}
```

Comment: woo. yeaaaah. D. Unit test that math code against known results; and all will be well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bug is in the `fall` function. We have

1. `delta`: a vector from the well to the ship
2. `force`: the magnitude of the gravity between these two bodies.

`|force|` is G * m1 * m2 / r^2

but `|delta|` is already r! so you are actually accelerating too fast. You need to divide by `r` again (basically normalizing the delta vector) before calling accelerate.

```
accelerate(delta * well.mass * mass / rSquared / Math.sqrt(rSquared))
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that even with the math bug(s) fixed, you're using [Euler integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) (i.e. `velocity += delta` and presumably `position += velocity`), so you're probably going to get some odd effects like rotation of the orbital ellipse over time, and perhaps the ellipse getting larger/smaller since Euler integration isn't guaranteed to conserve energy.

You might want to switch to [leapfrog integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration), which is energy-conserving and should work better for orbital mechanics.  Also, you should include the frame time in your equations so that the speed of your simulation is framerate-independent.